# JQuery search not displaying results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to search JSON file using JQuery code and the results are not displaying.

**Here is my code:**

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('subjects.json', function(data) {
        $("#searchInput2").keyup(function () {
          var searchField = $(this).val();
          if (searchField === "") {
            $("#searchdisplay").html("");
            return;
          }

          var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
          var output = '<div class="row">';

          $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (val.name.search(regex) != -1) {
              output += '<div">';
              output +=
                '<div class="form-group"><a class="dropdown-item">' +
                val.name +
                "</a></div>";
            }
          });
          output += "</div>";
          $("#searchdisplay").html(output);
        });


        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div class="form-group">
        <input  type="search"
          class="form-control"
          name="searchInput2"
          id="searchInput2"
        />
      </div>
      
      
       <div class="searchdisplay">
```

Here is my JSON file:

```
    {
   "Subjects": [
       {
          "name": "Programim 1",
          "Code": "01",
          "Semester": "1",
          "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
          "Professor": "Profesor 1",
          "Credits": "7",
          "Grade": "9",
          "Keywords": ["css","js","jquery","php"],
          "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
       },

       {
         "name": "Java programim",
         "Code": "02",
          "Semester": "2",
          "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
          "Professor": "Profesor2",
          "Credits": "6",
          "Grade": "9",
          "Keywords": ["css","js","jquery","php"],
          "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
       },

       {
         "name": "Programim 3 ",
        "Code": "03",
         "Semester": "7",
         "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
         "Professor": "Profesor 3",
         "Credits": "6",
         "Grade": "7",
         "Keywords": ["css","js","jquery","php"],
         "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
      },

      {
         "name": "Computer architecture",
        "Code": "04",
         "Semester": "2",
         "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
         "Professor": "Profesor 4",
         "Credits": "4",
         "Grade": "6",
         "Keywords": ["css","js","jquery","php"],
         "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
      },


      {
         "name": "Web Design",
        "Code": "05",
         "Semester": "4",
         "Type": ["Mandatory","Elective"],
         "Professor": "Profesor 5",
         "Credits": "4",
         "Grade": "7",
         "Keywords": ["css","js","jquery","php"],
         "Lecture": ["lecture","practical"]
      }


   ]
         

   

}
```

I want to display **all the information** of the subject when I search the subjects name so what changes in the code I need to make for it to work properly. Do I need to approach the search method differently or can I use my existing code with some changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your code iterates through the data given by the JSON file, you use the JQuery `$.each` method to iterate through all of the values in your JSON file. However, your JSON file is not an array, its an object. To iterate through all of the `Subjects` in the JSON file, iterate through `data.Subjects` instead of iterating through `data`.

```js
$.each(data.Subjects, function(key, val) {
  if (val.name.search(regex) != -1) {
    output += '<div">';
    output +=
      '<div class="form-group"><a class="dropdown-item">' +
      val.name + JSON.stringify(val) +
      "</a></div>";
  }
});
```

Then, using `val` you can display your data however you'd like. In this case, I used JSON.stringify to show all of the data within the `subjects.json` file, but I'm sure you could implement something more pretty for your application. For example, you could access a subject's professor with `val.Professor`, and display that using your `output` variable.

Comment: I did your changes still not displaying results

Comment: Does `<div class="searchdisplay"> ` have the closing tab `</div>`?

Comment: Yes it does have closing tag.

Comment: Do you link the index.js file?

Comment: You mean this command:   $.getJSON('subjects.json', function(data) {

Comment: Here's a repl.it with the code running. Maybe you'll be able to see what's missing: https://replit.com/@LukeTrenaman1/Stackoverflow-answer#index.html

Comment: I used your code that you put in replit.com and it worked, thank you for helping me.